# Is there a distortion of Earth's electric field by high objects, especially man-made?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, earth

Recently I've read one of Dr. Feynman's lectures about storms and lightnings. This one to be exact: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html

There he said, that human has the same charge as ground, when standing on it, and although Earth's electric field has strength of roughly 100V/m, it bends around human and looks like this:

[image]

And this leads to a question: if the object is much higher than a human, how exactly would electric field bend around it? Would it look roughly the same, thus making sort of a mound of strength < 100V around the object or would all these layers kind of take shape of an object*? Also would object protrude distortion far upwards, (almost not changing distance between 100V and 200 V layers) or would it cramp layers, thus making rapid growth in charge a small distance from the top of that object? Is there a formula describing how actually this happends?

[image]

Personally I think it would be like 'a' for small objects, such as human, and exponentially turning into 'd' for large objects, such as towers (not mountains, which are roughly mound-shaped themselves). But I'm not a physicist and would like to know for sure.

*I know these aren't layers, but a gradual growth, I use word "layer" for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

According to this video [How Powering with Atmospheric Electricity Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rVdEhyMR6A) connecting Earth's surface to sky using wire with needle on the end, we can get a very small current at ~120 meters. From several other articles (sadly they're all in russian, so it would probably be unreadable for most of people here) I've found out, that field strength needed for a corona discharge should be at least somwhere between 10kV/m and 15kV/m, which means, that at the top of the wire field strength was around that. So as a partial answer: lines seem to be heavily cramped at the top. Whether it would be mound-shaped, or follow shape of the bilding is yet unknown, same as exact formulas. But, since it was my question (and nobody answered it yet), I give myself the liberty of providing partial answer, which would be updated later.

To be continued...